# Windows detecting wrong time zone after taking Huawei router in use

Tags: windows, time-zone

So far Windows has (nearly) always correctly set the time zone automatically for me wherever I've been traveling, but after installing Huawei WiFi Mesh 7 routers to my home in Norway, Windows now automatically sets the time zone to UTC+8 (Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong...) when I'm home. Why?

I'm using Windows 11, and the left end of the task bar shows weather forecast for my home region, which is correct - so Windows does know my actual location, just doesn't use it for time zone for some reason. Location services are on. [www.iplocation.net](http://www.iplocation.net) shows my public IP address correctly (in Norway).

The router has correct time zone (Norway) in its settings, but could it be that it sends wrong time zone in dhcp response and Windows takes it from there? If so, can I somehow make Windows set time zone based on my GPS location instead (which I think would anyway be the only sensible option)?

I don't have other operating systems installed.

I know I can set the time zone manually as well, but I would highly prefer to let Windows set it automatically, because I'm traveling a lot and I'm used to have it this way.

[EDIT] DID SOME FURTHER TESTING:

1. Tried to connect the laptop to Internet via phone hotspot using mobile data - this did not fix the location, Windows still detected it as Shaoguan
2. Powered off all the Huawei routers - the location immediately changed to my home. After powering the routers back on, Windows location reverted to Shaoguan.
3. Connected the laptop to the Huawei router with Ethernet cable and disabled WiFi in the laptop - location got fixed again (to my home).

So it seems that the Huawei WiFi access points are advertising their location as Shaoguan, China, and Windows uses it (instead of IP-address-based or GPS-based location) even if not connected to the WiFi network in question.

Primarily I would of course like to get this fixed in the Huawei Mesh, but it seems to lack location configuration. In any case, I would also like to prevent Windows using WiFi networks as location source, as I really don't like the idea that anyone can set up a Wifi network advertising false location and Windows prioritizes it over reliable options such as GPS.

Comment: “could it be that it sends wrong time zone in dhcp response and Windows takes it from there?” - No

Comment: Hopefully, it's not routing all you traffic through China **;-)**

Comment: I've never used that router, but routers have a timezone setting and often have NTP server addresses they're configured with - update the timezone on the router and verify  if any NTP addresses are defaulted to non-generic addresses, then do a a NTP update on Windows to determine if the router is the issue; if not, what are the NTP settings in Windows?

Comment: Can't find anything about NTP server in the router settings, under "Network time" page it just says Sync status = synced and shows correct system time and time zone (which can be adjusted). Windows NTP server is time.nist.gov.

Comment: Also, now the weather forecast in Windows task bar has changed to show weather in Shaoguan, China instead of my actual location. I downloaded Windows Maps app and it also shows Shaoquan as my location. It doesn't say where it gets that location from (but it can only be the router) and there are no settings for changing it. This is very frustrating...

Comment: (Did some further testing and added the results to the original post)

Comment: @Jaggie Double check all wifi settings on the router's admin page since disabling WiFi resolves the issue, and unless mentioned in the router's manual, or on its support page, contact Huawei tech support since the issue goes away when shutting off all Huawei routers and immediately reappears as soon as they're powered back up.

Comment: Did some studying on the topic... Seems that the WiFi hotspots do not advertise their physical locations, but instead, companies such as Microsoft maintain databases of known WiFi hotspot MAC addresses and their respective locations. Then, when for example a Windows computer sees WiFi hotspots with specific MAC addresses, it will use such database to determine its own location. I have now requested Microsoft to remove the WiFi interface MAC addresses of all my Huawei routers from their database (via account.microsoft.com/privacy/location-services-opt-out), let's see if it helps...